# AS3 - ERROR In Applying Texture To Object With Alternativa3D 8

Tags: texture-mapping, 3d-modelling, 3ds

I use the `Alternativa3D 8` library / tool. I have a problem when applying texture to a 3D model.

I am coding with Actionscript 3 in Flash to make a player (*or displayer?*) of 3D objects (of `.3ds` format), which loads the 3D model and texture, and should give result of a "home". When I use the 3D model code in my program, I get the result of a "cube".

I want to get a result like : http://alternativa.ueuo.com/a1.png (used only 3d model and 1 texture).

[image]

but I have this result : http://alternativa.ueuo.com/a2.png, why?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what Answer you want from us. Obviously because you did it wrong. Because for `a2.png` you just pasted the texture maps onto a **cube**. Did you try making a "**house**" shape instead? Do you have link to the original tutorial? I mean compare your cube wireframe & their house wireframe.

Comment: Please read [**`How To Ask`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will guide you how to avoid your Question(s) being deleted. Give as much useful info to others who might try to help you. Two photos with "I want photo A but I got photo B" is not useful. What did you do to get `a1.png`? Why not re-create same process? How is this a **programming** question (or are you asking in wrong forum)?

Comment: У меня есть плеер 3д объектов, в которую загружаю 3д модель и текстура, и получаю "дом", а кода использую 3д модель в программу, получаю куб. Использую  Alternativa3D 8 в программирование.

Comment: Show the 3d model code by using [**`Edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42508157/edit) or show code using website like pastebin.com... No one can say what's wrong with your code if we can't see it.